# Takes a list and return a dict of distinct values pointing to a list of index locations of each value

Tags: python

I came up with a way to get a dict of distinct elements in a list pointing to the location of each element; it works, but I feel pretty awful about this code, it's very ugly. Is there a more natural/pythonic way to do this?

```
from itertools import groupby
sample_data = [1,2,3,3,1,0,5]
give_groups = lambda dta: {item: list(map(lambda z: z[0], list(item_group))) for item, item_group in itertools.groupby(list(enumerate(dta)), lambda x:x[1])}
print(give_groups(sample_data))
```

```
{1: [4], 2: [1], 3: [2, 3], 0: [5], 5: [6]}
```

The performance is also bad.

Created this alternate that does work, but is kinda slow:

```
def alt_grouping(dta):
    retdict = defaultdict(list)
    for position, item in enumerate(dta):
        retdict[item].append(position)
    return retdict
```

Comment: shouldn't be `1: [0,4] `?

Comment: AND IT DOESN'T EVEN WORK!

Comment: How did you check the runtime, what were your results, and what would you consider a reasonable result? (It's possible the Python startup time is responsible for any perceived slowness.) Do you know the range of the sample data in advance, so you could pre-fill the result data structure?

Comment: @Carbon What doesn't work, your code? Your question states it does. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Can you tell us more about what your input looks like?

Comment: `itertools.groupby` only works correctly if the data is already sorted, as written in the [documentation of the function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). As such, your code cannot work (and does not, as noted by @Alucard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first try :

```
from itertools import groupby
sample_data = [1,2,3,3,1,0,5]
give_groups = lambda dta: {item: list(map(lambda z: z[0], list(item_group))) for item, item_group in itertools.groupby(list(enumerate(dta)), lambda x:x[1])}
print(give_groups(sample_data))
```

Have to be corrected to:

```
from itertools import groupby # --> you don't have to call itertools.groupby just groupby
sample_data = [1,2,3,3,1,0,5]
give_groups = lambda dta: {item: list(map(lambda z: z[0], list(item_group))) for item, item_group in groupby(list(enumerate(dta)), lambda x:x[1])}
print(give_groups(sample_data))
```

But seems to be replacing items and not appending them, don't see why.

---

In the alt_grouping function, defaultdict doesn't exists:

```
def alt_grouping(dta):
    retdict = defaultdict(list) # don't know what is defaultdict
    for position, item in enumerate(dta):
        retdict[item].append(position)
    return retdict
```

Then I found a solution that works, it's based on your function alt_grouping:

```
sample_data = [1,2,3,3,1,0,5]

retdict = {}
for position, item in enumerate(sample_data):
        if item in retdict.keys():
            retdict[item].append(position)
        else:
            retdict[item] = [position]

print(retdict)
```

I take some execution & times testing in the first try and my alternative with a bigger sample a list of two range(100).

```
Sample Data:
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]

First Function:
{0: [100], 1: [101], 2: [102], 3: [103], 4: [104], 5: [105], 6: [106], 7: [107], 8: [108], 9: [109], 10: [110], 11: [111], 12: [112], 13: [113], 14: [114], 15: [115], 16: [116], 17: [117], 18: [118], 19: [119], 20: [120], 21: [121], 22: [122], 23: [123], 24: [124], 25: [125], 26: [126], 27: [127], 28: [128], 29: [129], 30: [130], 31: [131], 32: [132], 33: [133], 34: [134], 35: [135], 36: [136], 37: [137], 38: [138], 39: [139], 40: [140], 41: [141], 42: [142], 43: [143], 44: [144], 45: [145], 46: [146], 47: [147], 48: [148], 49: [149], 50: [150], 51: [151], 52: [152], 53: [153], 54: [154], 55: [155], 56: [156], 57: [157], 58: [158], 59: [159], 60: [160], 61: [161], 62: [162], 63: [163], 64: [164], 65: [165], 66: [166], 67: [167], 68: [168], 69: [169], 70: [170], 71: [171], 72: [172], 73: [173], 74: [174], 75: [175], 76: [176], 77: [177], 78: [178], 79: [179], 80: [180], 81: [181], 82: [182], 83: [183], 84: [184], 85: [185], 86: [186], 87: [187], 88: [188], 89: [189], 90: [190], 91: [191], 92: [192], 93: [193], 94: [194], 95: [195], 96: [196], 97: [197], 98: [198], 99: [199]}
--- 0.001995563507080078 seconds ---
My Function:
{0: [0, 100], 1: [1, 101], 2: [2, 102], 3: [3, 103], 4: [4, 104], 5: [5, 105], 6: [6, 106], 7: [7, 107], 8: [8, 108], 9: [9, 109], 10: [10, 110], 11: [11, 111], 12: [12, 112], 13: [13, 113], 14: [14, 114], 15: [15, 115], 16: [16, 
116], 17: [17, 117], 18: [18, 118], 19: [19, 119], 20: [20, 120], 21: [21, 121], 22: [22, 122], 23: [23, 123], 24: [24, 124], 25: [25, 125], 26: [26, 126], 27: [27, 127], 28: [28, 128], 29: [29, 129], 30: [30, 130], 31: [31, 131], 32: [32, 132], 33: [33, 133], 34: [34, 134], 35: [35, 135], 36: [36, 136], 37: [37, 137], 38: [38, 138], 39: [39, 139], 40: [40, 140], 41: [41, 141], 42: [42, 142], 43: [43, 143], 44: [44, 144], 45: [45, 145], 46: [46, 146], 47: 
[47, 147], 48: [48, 148], 49: [49, 149], 50: [50, 150], 51: [51, 151], 52: [52, 152], 53: [53, 153], 54: [54, 154], 55: [55, 155], 56: [56, 156], 57: [57, 157], 58: [58, 158], 59: [59, 159], 60: [60, 160], 61: [61, 161], 62: [62, 
162], 63: [63, 163], 64: [64, 164], 65: [65, 165], 66: [66, 166], 67: [67, 167], 68: [68, 168], 69: [69, 169], 70: [70, 170], 71: [71, 171], 72: [72, 172], 73: [73, 173], 74: [74, 174], 75: [75, 175], 76: [76, 176], 77: [77, 177], 78: [78, 178], 79: [79, 179], 80: [80, 180], 81: [81, 181], 82: [82, 182], 83: [83, 183], 84: [84, 184], 85: [85, 185], 86: [86, 186], 87: [87, 187], 88: [88, 188], 89: [89, 189], 90: [90, 190], 91: [91, 191], 92: [92, 192], 93: 
[93, 193], 94: [94, 194], 95: [95, 195], 96: [96, 196], 97: [97, 197], 98: [98, 198], 99: [99, 199]}
--- 0.0009963512420654297 seconds ---
```

Seems to be pretty similar then I try with list(range(10000)):

```
First Function:
--- 0.015984535217285156 seconds ---
My Function:
--- 0.005953311920166016 seconds ---
```

Here we see a difference.

There is the code for tests - EDITED :

```
import time
sample_data = list(range(1000000)) + list (range(1000000))
# print ("Sample Data:\n",sample_data, "\n")

print("First Function:")
start_time = time.time()

from itertools import groupby
give_groups = lambda dta: {item: list(map(lambda z: z[0], list(item_group))) for item, item_group in groupby(list(enumerate(dta)), lambda x:x[1])}
# print(give_groups(sample_data))
give_groups(sample_data)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))


print("My Function:")
start_time = time.time()
retdict = {}
for position, item in enumerate(sample_data):
        if item in retdict.keys():
            retdict[item].append(position)
        else:
            retdict[item] = [position]

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))



print("Other Function:")

from collections import defaultdict

start_time = time.time()
def dict_with_indices(dta):
    """ Returns a dictionary with a list of indices for each item in dta

    Args:
        dta (list): list of data to be indexed

    Returns:
        dict: dict with list of indices as values

    Examples:
        >>> dict_with_indices([1,2,3,3,1,0,5]]
        {1: [0, 4], 2: [1], 3: [2, 3], 0: [5], 5: [6]}
    """
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for idx, val in enumerate(dta):
        result[val].append(idx)
    return result

dict_with_indices(sample_data)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Times for this new tests:

```
First Function:
--- 1.9537413120269775 seconds ---
My Function:
--- 0.7061352729797363 seconds ---
Other Function:
--- 0.6053769588470459 seconds ---
```

New Solution seems to be the better one, thanks to @agtoever :

```
from collections import defaultdict
    

    def dict_with_indices(dta):
        """ Returns a dictionary with a list of indices for each item in dta
    
        Args:
            dta (list): list of data to be indexed
    
        Returns:
            dict: dict with list of indices as values
    
        Examples:
            >>> dict_with_indices([1,2,3,3,1,0,5]]
            {1: [0, 4], 2: [1], 3: [2, 3], 0: [5], 5: [6]}
        """
        result = defaultdict(list)
        for idx, val in enumerate(dta):
            result[val].append(idx)
        return result
    
    dict_with_indices(sample_data)
```

Comment: It makes the same as you alt_grouping function but I don't think that neither are slow. Can specify how you evaluate this?

Comment: I edited my awnser, with all explained :)

Comment: Thank you. I've retracted my down vote :) I find it a little hard to follow but that's the only problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You could shorten your code and increase readability by replacing the if-else with a `defaultdict` [like this](https://tio.run/##hVFNa4QwEL37K4Y9KYTiR7cHYYUe@gd6FVlSM3YDaiQZW5fS324nardSCo2QNxnnvcy8DFe6mD6b58aaDmrTtliTNr0D3Q3GEihs5NiS0jUFAR/AR@d3TZez7jlGFyqSUR4Ar8PhAM9Io2W@XCpZStor@HrOtNoRmAY2JjTGAsr6Apqw4yywVLAoPdpXt2r6xWkIPTnKbxpKcpIMvKCXwwnVytzu35G5jXzZ1zZ@NyEdvMl2RLfynybZDS3uBIqi@GPqMhGpyPhLRCyOVXUr/0hyKGMB95WAlMOEMWNMGTiMOTwyHhkfqs9v3xa06NhrOO1dX@defnu7tJqE79e7hf3YoZWEuyf4kSm5qrqTw4C9CpkWbVd4e7aSebC6p/Df4aJo/gI).

Comment: Ok, I will add it to the awnser with times.

Answer (score -2):

> #This is simple understandable code

```
alpha=['a','b','c','d','e']#list
dic={}#dict

alpha.sort(reverse=True)
length=len(alpha)

for key in range (length):
    value=alpha.pop()
    dic[key]=value

print(dic)
```

Comment: Please can you explain how this is better than the OPs code. Code Review is here to teach people to fish, not just give them one. Additionally this looks like it doesn't work the same way.